# Не вызывается коллбек при нажатии кнопки Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть такая иерархия с канвасом и кнопкой:

[image]

GraphicsRaycaster на объекте с канвасом, в сцене есть EventSystem, который видит кнопку и логгирует нажатие по ней в событии pointerPress, то есть инпут как бы работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку привязанная функция не вызывается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

происходит просто клик с хайлайтом графики кнопки и всё. В чём может быть проблема, что забыл добавить/настроить?

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено, был перекрывающий объект, который принимал на себя рейкаст, будьте внимательнее :)